# fill an ordered series in column A only if its corresponding cell in B having any text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want that if in `column B` having text then in corresponding cell of `column A` number should be filled according to previous entry or so called series.

I tried this for A1 `=IF(B1=="","",1)` but it is not working. I dragged it for all cells of `column A` but its filling `1` in all those cells.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with use of last column to make right series. What is did is as:

- Define name of `XFD1` as `X` and assign value 0 to it.
- Assign formula

> XFD2=IF(B2="","",1)

to XFD2 and drag it for 1000 or more cells as of need.

- Now for A2, it will be start point of series, assign this formula:

> A2=IF(B2="","",SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(X),COLUMN(X))):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(XFD2)))))

- Now drag it for equivalent cells as you dragged in XFD column

This will fill an ordered series in column A only if its corresponding cell in B having any text.

Answer (score 1):

You are headed in the right direction, but the syntax of your IF statement is off. The syntax for the IF function is as follows;

> IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])

So to do what you are are asking, you need to satisfy the 3 elements.

1. The logical test of `B1` to see if it has "nothing" in it. This only needs a single equal sign; `B1=""`
2. If the logical test is true (nothing in `B1`), tell it what it should do. In your case, nothing; `""`
3. If the logical test is false (something in `B1` ), the cell `A1` is populated with the value of a cell reference, formula, specific text or a fixed number; `1` (or whatever value you wish).

Putting it all together; `=IF(B1="","",1)` or `=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"",1)`

Once you have the formula working in `A1`, copy it to `A2` and modify it as follows to add one to the previous value; `=IF(B1="","",SUM(A1+1))`. Now you can copy it from `A2` to the rest of the cells in the `Column A`.

Comment: "write" direction??

Comment: @teylyn LOL...good catch.

Comment: @Tab how does Sum(A1:current_cell) come into the mix? that is not mentioned in your question. Maybe you need to make up your mind about what you want to achieve and then post these requirements. Moving the goal post and sending the experts here on a wild goose chase by not giving the full specs will not get you much support. Get clear about your data input, processing logic and data output. Just don't add variations of the expected result with every comment.

Comment: Can you please forget about using two equal signs for comparison.  The == in a formula will NOT do any good. It is NOT VALID EXCEL SYNTAX. Please use only one = sign to compare values. You cannot use a formula to sum values including the current cell, since that would be a circular reference. Again, as already asked above, please provide a data sample. You don't have to provide it here. There are thousands of sites that allow file sharing. Use them and share a file. Mock up the expected results manually, so we know what to aim for. Make it easy for people here to help you.

Comment: @teylyn oh yeah I got stuck with it ;) well sum will work only if I add 1 in the last cell having an entry. I want to add snap shot but this site asking for rating points.

Comment: And oops that == came in my mind due to in programming i use this and here it was working well thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Tab, I've said it several times before, but maybe you need the repeats: there are OTHER sites on the internet where you can post images or files, for crying out loud. Just use them and then post a flipping link. What can be so hard? I find your verbal explanations so self-immersed and not obvious to people who don't know your setup that it hurts. Please have some consideration for those trying to help you and make it EASY for us. Get on Dropbox or Skydrive or whatever and post a sample file with expected outcome mocked up manually. Then you don't need rep points here to post your scenario.

Comment: I have uploaded it as my profile pic

Answer (score 0):

In Excel the comparison operator for "is equal to" is a single = sign, not two.

I assume that with "previous entry" you are referring to the cell above. It is not quite clear what you want to show. If you want a 1 only in the rows where column B has a value, then try

```
=if(B1="","",1)
```

and copy down.

If that does not answer your question, please provide a bit more detail. A screenshot with the desired results mocked up manually would be a start.

Comment: Whatever u said I wrote in my question that I tried it. Btw this forum asking for 10 reputation point to post a snap

Comment: Can you try plain English, please? Earning 10 rep points is not that hard. If you don't want to make that effort, post a screenshot on any of the free file sharing sites and then post a link here. How hard can it be?